# Stimulate REAL mouse release event

Tags: python, windows, mouseevent, pywin32, pynput

I am trying to trigger a mouse left click event then release that click so it should be like a real mouse click.

I am currently doing it like that:

```py
def click(x,y): 
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

I've also tried [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) like that:

```py
mouse.click(Button.left)
```

and:

```py
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)
```

So, all the three codes works fine and they almost work the same way... But try a real mouse click on https://cookie.riimu.net/speed/ then try the click made using Python on the same site.

- The real mouse click is like that (GIF picture): https://i.vgy.me/l6JMtn.gif
- But, the click made using Python is like that (GIF picture): https://i.vgy.me/dHSkux.gif

So as you can see, in the real mouse click: the circle pops in then pops out. But in the Python mouse click, the circle pops in and doesn't pop out again.

What can be causing that? And is there's any possible fix?

Comment: So inserting any kind of realistic delay in between the mouse events doesn't help?

Comment: @RandomDavis - What's the delay interval that you recommend? I've tried a lot of milliseconds but they all resulted in the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd ask me that, as I've never measured the average time between clicking the mouse button and releasing it. My wild guess is maybe like `200ms`

Answer (score 0):

30 milliseconds is a correct delay between the click and the release.

So this would stimulate a real left mouse click and release:

```py
def click(x,y): 
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    time.sleep(30 / 1000)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```